# Subir imagen en Lavarel 5 encriptar y borrar con Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Tengo un problema con Dropzone.js para borrar imagenes luego de ser encryptada y subida con Laravel 5 tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
            $extension       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ?: 'png';
            $fileName        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $folderName      = '/uploads/images/posts/' . date("Ym", time()) .'/'.date("d", time());
            $destinationPath = public_path() . $folderName;
            $safeName        = md5($fileName).'.'.$extension;
            $file->move($destinationPath, $safeName);
```

Una vez encrytada y subida mediante ajax con Dropzone si el user se equivoca de foto o sube la misma por error o equivocacion deberia ser eliminada por el mismo usuario antes de ser publicada

Coloco el codigo JS de Dropzone que uso, pero ese codigo me envia el nombre original del archivo mas no el encrytado en L5

```
Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
  paramName: 'image',
  maxFilesize: 10, // MB
  maxFiles: 1,
  dictDefaultMessage: 'Click para subir una imagen',
  previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
  previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
  init: function() {
    this.on('success', function( file, resp ){
      //console.log(resp.url);
      $('#file').attr( 'value',resp.name);
    });

    this.on('thumbnail', function(file) {
      if ( file.width < 200 || file.height < 200 ) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      } else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
    this.on('removedfile', function(file) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: site_path + '/post/ajaxdeletefile',
        data: {id: file.name},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
        //  console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  },

  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() {
      done('The image must be at least 640 x 480px')
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si solo necesitas una imagen en dicha carpeta donde se guardara lo que puedes hacer es leer el nombre del archivo

```
function listar_archivos($carpeta){
    if(is_dir($carpeta)){
        if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
            while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                    echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.$carpeta.'/'.$archivo.'">'.$archivo.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            closedir($dir);
        }
    }
}

echo listar_archivos('\tu\directorio');
```

esto si solo necesitas una imagen por cada post asi puedes eliminar del lado del server